# Connect to phpmysqladmin, error

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am new to php and need some help to solve my error!

I know there is some older posts about this, that I have read, but it did not gave me any clue, So please give me a helping hand!

The error is this:

> Notice:
>   Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\wamp\www\tutorial.php on line 12
>
> Error:
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\tutorial.php on line 12

And the line is this:

```
 !$mysqli->query($con, "INSERT INTO newdatabase(name, age, email) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
```

If someone could give me some syntax for writing howe to put in values in the db, that would solve this! Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more code so we can help you.

Comment: Think I have just solved it! I use this syntax: mysqli_query. Thanks –  Athanasios Emmanouilidis for your interest!!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified `$MySQLi`.

Try this:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'username';
$dbpasswd = 'p@55w0rd';
$dbname = 'database';

$MySQLi = new MySQLi($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd, $dbname);
if($MySQLi->connect_error) {
    die("Problem connecting to database. - ".$MySQLi->error);
}

$MySQLi->query("INSERT INTO newdatabase(name, age, email) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
```

Then, if you ever use `$MySQLi` in functions, don't forget to specify it like `global $MySQLi` :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Peter Bishop, I have solved it. And it was only that line in the code thatwas making errors. I have specified $MySQLi earlier in the php file.

Comment: Oh, okay! Glad it's all sorted!